# Probability of at least one success in a series of independent, non-identical Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Let's say I have a set of independent Bernoulli trials each with a different probability:

$$
x_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p_i)
$$

The number of successes (sum of *x*) will be distributed according to the [Poisson-Binomail distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution):

$$
S = \sum_{i = 0}^n x_i \sim \operatorname{PoissonBinomial}(p)
$$

However, I am interested in the the probability that there is at least 1 success. In other words:

$$
S > 0 \sim  \cdots\text{?}
$$

Comment: $S>0$ has a distribution. $p(S>0)$ can be calculated, but does not itself have a distribution. Which are you asking?

Comment: Sorry, yes what I'm interested in is the distribution of $S > 0$. Thank you

Comment: S>0 is a binary event (yes, no) so the *distribution* for it is Bernoulli.

Comment: Hint: write out all of the events that would need to be considered in order to calculate the probability of s. Then see if you notice an easier way to find the probability.

Comment: Okay, so I think that the answer should be $S > 0 \sim Bernoulli(1 - \sum(1 - p))$.

I think what I'm _actually_ interested in is the distribution of $1 - \sum(1 - p)$. But of course, that's not the question that I asked.

Comment: The distribution of $1 - \sum_i (1 - p_i)$ depends on the distribution of the $p$s. If the $p$s are known exactly, then the distribution of $1 - \sum_i (1 - p_i)$ is a delta function.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: S=0 means all the $x_i$ are 0, so why are you summing $1-p_i$?

Comment: Whoops - I meant product, not sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that there is at least one success is P(S>0).

Because there can't be less than S successes and S is a discrete quantity, then: P(S>0) = 1 - P(S=0)

Each trial has a probability of success p_i, so it has a probability of failure (1-p_i)

P(S=0) = P(all fail)

Because the n trials are independent, then P(all fail) = P(trial 1 fails) * ... * P(trial n fails)

And those are the (1-p_i), so:

P(S=0) = (1-p_1) * ... * (1-p_n)

So your answer is:

P(S>0) = 1 - (1-p_1) * ... * (1-p_n)